# Getting Entity Malformed Exception error while adding a taxonomy term in drupal7

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-entities

I'm using Drupal7. When i'm adding a new term in a taxonomy vocabulary getting the following 
error.

"Entity Malformed excetion : Missing bundle property on entity of type node.in entity_extract_ids()(line 7409 of /home/clutch2/sitename/html/drupal/includes/common.inc."

And when i'm viewing the list of terms in the taxonomy vocabulary in which i attempted to

add a new one, that showing the term which i added. What i have to do to get rid out of

this error message ?Can Anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be caused by the several reason, depending which modules are you using.

- [This could be caused by the Drupal core bug, where database records not deleted for Term Reference Fields after Term is
  Deleted](http://drupal.org/node/1281114)
- [by Feeds module, where importing of the data fails and so an orphan node of sorts is created without a title or any data.](http://drupal.org/node/1394320)
- [Search API when using database search index](http://drupal.org/node/1402270)
- [Views, where hook_field_formatter_prepare_view never called for entity fields attached to the current node on a node page](http://drupal.org/node/1473228)

---

**Solution:**

[Taxonomy Orphanage module](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_orphanage) should help you with removing orphaned taxonomy term references from entities as currently this is not fixed yet in the Drupal 7.x core.
If this won't work, try [Field reference delete module](http://drupal.org/sandbox/drothstein/1775816).

---

You can also track the problem manually.
Here is sql query which I've used to track the invalid references:

```
drush sqlq "SELECT nid, title from node WHERE nid IN (select entity_id from  field_data_field_some_ref WHERE field_some_ref_tid not IN (select tid from taxonomy_term_data));"
```

Where field_data_field_some_ref is data field of field_some_ref which is type of 'Term reference'.

Comment: When using taxonomy_orphanage on a multilingual site, make sure to install this patch: https://www.drupal.org/node/1904132#comment-7149502 - otherwise it will fail to remove the obsolete references.

Usage with drush: `drush tor`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it's a Drupal 7.8 Update Issue, you can find how to fix it [here](http://drupal.org/node/1266620) and [here](http://www.jordanpeterson.me/blog/drupal-78-upgrade-issues)

Hope that helps.